# Updating documents using pagination consistently ignores half of the documents

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I have a very big database of 300k - 400k documents and in that I have to update some fields from `string` type to `number` type using `parseInt`, periodically, say every week. I created a view using the `typeof` operator for one of the fields and query the view for all `string` keys and update those docs.

Here's my view's `map` function:

```js
function (doc) {
  if (typeof doc.xyz !== 'undefined') {
    emit(typeof doc.xyz, null);
  }
}
```

And then here's how I update my documents:

```js
function updateProperties(skip,field) {
    var options = {reduce: false, limit: 1500, include_docs: true, key: "string"};
    if(skip)
        options.skip = skip;
    db.query('test_indexes/'+field+'_type',options)
        .then(function(result){
            console.log('>  Currently at offset: '+ result.offset);
            result = result.rows.map(function(one) {
                return one.doc;
            });
            if(result.length) {
                for(var i=0 ;i< result.length; i++) {
                    if(field in result[i] && result[i][field]) {
                        try {
                            result[i][field] = parseInt(result[i][field],10);
                        }
                        catch(err) {
                            console.log('Error converting '+field+' at page '+page+' field: '+result[i][field]+ err.stack);
                        }
                    }
                }
                page++;
                (function(page,findResult){
                    db.bulkDocs(findResult).then(function (result) {
                        totalDone+= result.length;
                        console.log('Done uploading page '+page+' of '+field+' > '+ 'Total Records updated: '+ totalDone);
                            updateProperties(totalDone,field);
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        delete err.data;
                        console.log('Error updating bulkdocs for '+field+': '+ JSON.stringify(err));
                        updateProperties(totalDone,field);
                    });
                })(page,result);
            }
            else {
                fieldsConverted++;
                totalDone = 0;
                page = 0;
                if(fieldsConverted === convert.length) {
                    console.log('******************************* DONE WITH '+ convert[fieldsConverted-1]+'**********************');
                    console.log('All done, Yay!');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('******************************* DONE WITH '+ convert[fieldsConverted-1]+'**********************');
                    updateProperties(null, convert[fieldsConverted]);
                }
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error while bulk fetching'+ JSON.stringify(err));
        });
}
```

And when run it gives the below output:

```
>  Currently at offset: 0
Done uploading page 1 of xyz >Total Records updated: 1500
>  Currently at offset: 3000
^C
abc@TempMach:~/aire20$ node server/data/bulkUpdate.js
>  Currently at offset: 3000
Done uploading page 1 of xyz >Total Records updated: 1500
>  Currently at offset: 6000
Done uploading page 2 of xyz >Total Records updated: 3000
>  Currently at offset: 9000
```

Now as you can see, when I want to skip 1500 docs I expect my offset to be 1500 and not 3000 after updating. At the end, if say I have 10 docs as a whole, it only updates 5 of them and says ***All done*** and exits. What am I missing?